# Left Job with all acounts, etc. with personal email

Tags: email

I have worked at a startup company for the past year, and I have decided to leave the company after a rough end.  The company was basically falling apart, everyone was fighting with each other and the boss and I did not get along.  After I left I realize that I am an admin for all of their online stuff.  I am the only one with access to their website, access to their google business page, etc.

It's all connected to my personal email,  and I want to get rid of it.  They have not contacted me about any of it, and its been over 1 month.  I am just getting tired of seeing all their info every time I look at my personal email etc.

Can I just delete everything?  Since i am the admin i can't really just leave and let it stay up, I can delete it or keep it up.

Could this be breaking the law in any sorts or anything?

p.s The boss never gave us business email, so we had to use our personal emails most of the time.  I never thought it would end like this either, so I didn't mind using my own email.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

What's the worst that can happen? If you do nothing, it's a bit inconvenient. If you delete all that company's stuff, who knows what they could sue you for. I'm not saying they would be right, but being sued can be expensive, no matter whether you are wrong or right.

Send a letter by registered mail, with a witness to the contents, that you are the only one with admin rights to these sites, and asking them how they would like to take over these sites, and informing them that you will delete anything on your personal email after a reasonable time if you don't hear from them. And since anything you do is work for you, you should expect some appropriate compensation.

Deleting their property, even if it affects you, is risky.

Comment: For what it is worth, I have sued someone on a client's behalf for just the kind of conduct in connection with a start up company that you note could result in a lawsuit, and it was about a month after the break that the suit was filed.